# E.123 Format Phone number in python based on country

Tags: python, formatting, python-phonenumber

I am trying to format phone numbers using https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/
It is working. But is there a way I could verify if this would comply E.123/E.164 formatting ? Appreciate any help.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

```
def format_phone_number(contact):
phone_number = contact.get('phone_number')
country_code = contact.get('country')

if phone_number and country_code:
    try:
        country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=country_code)
        if country:
            formatted_number = phonenumbers.format_number(
                phonenumbers.parse(
                    phone_number, country.alpha_2
                ), phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL
            )
            return formatted_number
    except (phonenumbers.NumberParseException, AttributeError):
        pass

return None
```